# Operation name is not coming in WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have created a WCF service and my interface looks like below:-

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
 {    
   [OperationContract(Action = "GetData")]
   CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);   
 }
```

here i am using Action name and when i am generating WSDL from this service i am getting operation name like below :

[image]

but when i am using wildcard for action like below :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
 {    
   [OperationContract(Action = "*")]
   CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);   
 }
```

here i am not getting operation name in my WSDL.

[image]

My question is that how can i use wildcard by generating operation name in WSDL. Please help me to solve this issue or give me suggestions for achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `[OperationContract(Action = "*")]` if your service operation takes a Message object and returns a Message object or void.

See [the MSDN documentation for OperationContractAttribute.Action Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action(v=vs.110).aspx)